# Radgrid very slow to render on page refresh

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

When I initially load a page that has our radgrid on it, the page loads in seconds.  When I refresh the exact same page, the page load takes minutes.  I'd post code, but I'm not sure it's relevant - as the code doesn't change from initial page load to page refresh.  So this is a more general question, has anyone had any difficulties/experiences with radgrid rendering very slowly on page refresh vs initial load?

Comment: Have you find out what the problem was?

Comment: @felicem it was the viewstate

Comment: How is the viewstate different from the first load of the page and the subsequent F5 refresh of the page? It does not make sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the viewstate. I disabled it for the entire page (just doing it for the grid did no good) and the page loads/refreshes quickly. There is a whole host of new issues that arises with the viewstate now disabled, but we're working through those.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without code and results of checks on database connection.

However, one of the most common issues that cause such behavior is about columns without or with wrong datafield in the db.

Check and make sure that each column you have, **even hidden columns**, have their datafield in the db. Happened to me that an hidden column had a typo in the datafield and this was causing a similar problem.

Check that the data type of your columns correspond to the datatype in the db.

Test your grid on different web browser and eventually update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with Telerik controls (particularly RadGrid) for a number of years and have never needed to disable view state - If you have Telerik support I would encourage you to contact them with you problem, if you don't have support you can still access the documentation at http://telerik.com/help there is also a very useful forum available.